# jest mock for multiple cases

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

`file.js`:

```js
import fun1 from './fun1';

export function file() {
  if (fun1) {
    return 'hello world';
  } else {
    return 'good bye';
  }
}
```

I want to cover all branch for file.js in my test file

```
// file-test.js

describe('test fun1', () => {
    it('should return hello world when fun1 is true', async() => {
        // expect blabla
    });
    it('should return good bye when fun1 is false', async() => {
        // expect blabla
    });
});
```

In this case, how to jest mock fun1 in file-test?
Thank you so much!